# Alert handling in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate the login of my college website but the site is behaving kinda awkward nowadays. It is showing an alert for signing(which doesn't work though) and the link keeps on loading. When the alert is canceled then the site loads completely.
I'm using selenium and the next line to driver.get method only executes if the site is loaded completely.
the link is https://learn.upes.ac.in/

Comment: Can't you simply dismiss the alert and log-in as you'd normally?

Comment: post some code?

Comment: @Mast yes i'm trying to do it.. but get() waits for page to load completely then only the next statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

user this method to dismiss the popup prompt and continue with your (normal) method of login.

```
driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
```

Comment: No the site is designed in such a way that when the alert will be cancelled or sign in is clicked then only the page will load... otherwise it'll be in loading state only. and get() only works if page is completely loaded. and there is no entry of Alert in the HTML of the page